# Rigify Animbox addon Armature origin not moving problem

Tags: blender, blender-2.61, blender-2.67

I am using **Rigify Animbox when move my Armature and start animation it move last position and when go to edit mode it show many link that connect with Armature.
this link can't set origin or can't move please help me how can fix it**.

*please see below video so you can better understand my problem.*

Link: https://screenrec.com/share/AkR59zCZrL

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a keyframe in Object mode. That makes the whole armature jump to the center of the world (which is where the keyframe is recorded). Just delete all keyframes on the object level and you'll be able to move the Armature object.